# FormView call a string function in bind

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an edit user page inside my website (edituser.aspx). The username and password are placed in an Access database and i show them inside a FormView. like this:

```
<asp:FormView 
ID="EditForm" 
runat="server" 
DefaultMode="Edit">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <strong>username:</strong><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="usernameIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("usernameID") %>' /><br />

        <strong>Password:</strong><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="passwordIDTextBox" TextMode="password" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("passwordID") %>' /><br />
    ... .
```

I encrypted the password in the database but although I have a decrypt function for it but **i don't know how to use it inside the Bind phrase**. For Example i tried

```
 <%# decrypt(Bind("passwordID")) %>
```

and this didn't work.

NOTE: I use asp.net 3.5 and This is my function for decrypt  inside edituser.aspx.vb:

```
Public Function Decrypt(ByVal strDecoded_Pword As String) As String
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim i, ct As Integer
        Dim letter, dec, StrValappend, strVal As String
        dec = ""
        strDecoded_Pword = StrReverse(strDecoded_Pword)

        For ct = 1 To Len(strDecoded_Pword) Step 2
            StrValappend = Chr(Val("&H" & (Mid(strDecoded_Pword, ct, 2))))
            strVal = strVal & StrValappend
        Next
        strDecoded_Pword = strVal

        For i = 1 To Len(strDecoded_Pword)
            letter = Mid(strDecoded_Pword, i, 1)
            dec = dec & Chr(Asc(letter) - i - 5)
        Next
        Decrypt = dec
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try Eval instead of Bind:

```
<%# Decrypt(Eval("passwordID")) %>
```

Comment: If i switch from Bind to Eval. An error will raise : No value given for one or more required parameters.